# Checking a variable state

Tags: python

I am facing a problem at the moment... I am trying to make a naughts and crosses game, and i am trying to decided whether the user has guessed outside of the grid... this is the code that i have so far come up with and the outcome is that the code crashes, please could you help?

The code below is what i am currently running to get this outcome.

```
        if 'users input' in (command = to left):
            Left_new = input("How many places would you like to move left")))

        elif 'users input' in (command = right):
            Right_new = input("How many places would you like to move right")))

        elif 'users input' in (= to up):
           up_new = input("How many places would you like to move up")))

        elif 'users input' in (= down ):
            Down_new =input("How many places would you like to move down")))

        else:
            if  ( users input <9) or ( users input > 100 ):
                print("Sorry one of your inputs were invalid...")
```

Comment: check position before you do `y -= step` (etc.) and skip this move. Or move it back to previous position when you check `if  ( x > grid_size or x < 0) or ( y > grid_size or y < 0 ):`

Comment: I'm just wondering what the hell are these if-statements like `elif 'users input' in (= to up):`

Comment: sorry i am not very good at this sort of thing...

Comment: i have realised the nonsense that this question has bought, and have tried to remove it. However this request has been denied... would you potentially know how to help?

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating a `while` statement and `break` from it if the data input is good.
i.e.

```
while True:
    Down_position = (int(input("How many places would you like to move down")))
    step = Down_position
    if (step + x <= grid_size) and (step + x >= 0):
        x += step
        break
    else:
        print ("Sorry, that isn't on the grid")
        print_board(board)
```

Here is some working code (only using Down) as an example.

```
def print_grid():
    print (0,top)
    print ("-----------------------------------")
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print (i,grid[i])
    print ("-----------------------------------")
x = 0
y = 0
top =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
grid=[]
for i in range(10):
    grid.append([0]*10)

grid_size = len(grid)-1
while True:
    while True:
        Down_position = (int(input("How many places would you like to move down ")))
        step = Down_position
        if (step + x <= grid_size) and (step + x >= 0):
            grid[x][y] = 0
            x += step
            grid[x][y] = 1
            print_grid()
            break
        else:
            print("******************************")
            print ("Sorry, that isn't on the grid")
            print("******************************")
            print_grid()
```

Comment: That code would go after `elif cmd in ('D', 'DOWN', 'B', 'BOTTOM'):` You would need to edit it appropriately for the other inputs, Up,Right and Left